# Bootstrap 5 carousel carousel-caption text overlapped when I use JavaScript to append html content to the <div class="carousel-inner">

Tags: javascript, html, css

I was able to get the Bootstrap 5 carousel with carousel-caption working in a static pages with multiple <div class "item"> Here is the page with static contents and it works.

```
<div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="item active">
    <img src="http://www.gettyimages.ca/gi-resources/images/Homepage/Hero/UK/CMS_Creative_164657191_Kingfisher.jpg" alt="Los Angeles" style="width:100%;">
    <div class="carousel-caption">
       <h3>CAPTION 1123</h3>
       <p>LA is always so much fun!</p>
    </div>
    </div>
   <div class="item">
     <img src="http://www.gettyimages.ca/gi-resources/images/Homepage/Hero/UK/CMS_Creative_164657191_Kingfisher.jpg" alt="Chicago" style="width:100%;">
  <div class="carousel-caption">
    <h3>CAPTION 235</h3>
    <p>OC is always so much fun!</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="item">
  <img src="http://www.gettyimages.ca/gi-resources/images/Homepage/Hero/UK/CMS_Creative_164657191_Kingfisher.jpg" alt="Chicago" style="width:100%;">
  <div class="carousel-caption">
       <h3>CAPTION 555</h3>
    <p>SD is always so much fun!</p>
   </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

But if If I replace the page with this

```
<div class="carousel-inner">

</div>
```

Then I filled the div class="item" with dynamic contents using PHP fetching from a mysql database.
Then I used JavaScript to append all the div class="item" as follow :

```
const divBtag = index === 0 ? '<div class="carousel-item active">' : '<div class="carousel-item">';
      //const divBtag = '<div class="carousel-item">';
         var photoHtml =
                        divBtag +
                           '<img src="' + photo.photo_path + '" class="d-block" 
                            style="width:100%" />' +
                        '</div>' +
                         '<div class="carousel-caption">'  +
                             '<h5>' + photo.photo_description + '</h5>' +
                             '<p>' + photo.photo_datetime + '</p>' +
                         '</div>' +
                       '</div>';
      

            $('.carousel-inner').append(photoHtml);
```

The "carousel-caption" text in "h3" tag will show overlapped with item 0 and item 1 and only the last item 2 work fine. and the text in "p" tag also show overlapped text with item 0 and item 1 only the last item 2 work fine. Is that a way to fix that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a div wrap around the "h5" and "p" tag as shown in the following html code resolve the overlapped text issue.

```
  const divBtag = (index === 0) ? '<div class="carousel-item active">' : '<div class="carousel-item">';
  const photoHtml =
  divBtag +
    '<img src="' + photo.photo_path + '" class="d-block" style="width:100%" />' +
   '<div class="carousel-caption">' +
       '<div>' +
          '<h5>' + photo.photo_description + '</h5>' +
          '<p>' + photo.photo_datetime + '</p>' +
       '</div>' +
    '</div>' +
  '</div>';

$('.carousel-inner').append(photoHtml);
```